# Export to Excel tool for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

Is there any tool that can export a dynamically generated html to excel in c sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

Answer (score 1):

why do u want to write functionality that already exists. mean excel has it, u can import any web page (just to note excel uses IE engine to render tags).
here are steps how it can be achieved.

Open `excel`; go to `Data` Tab; click `From Web`;

`New Web Query` child window opens.

write into `Address Bar` and go to the web page u wan to import.

after page loads into the window click `import` button

that's all.

(i assumed u are using ms office 2007, if diff version, diff steps)

**just one more note. ms office uses IE rendering engine, so not all tags are supported, so if it looks ugly, do not blame me ;)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to export html to Excel. In Excel we are talking about rows and columns while html is a document. You would probably want to export html to Word or pdf.

In any case, for creating Excel files in C# I've used the following 2 libraries: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/biffcsharp.aspx and http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: I want to export a html report to excel such that the excel report will have the same format as that of the html report. I was able to export the html report but the format is not as required

Comment: How does this html document look like? I assume it's a table, or something that can be transformed into a table...

Comment: the html consists of an outer table and four tables within this outer table. The first inner table have three columns, the 2nd table have two columns the 3 table can have any number of columns which is decided at run time and the 4th table have three columns.